# Best way of CSS override?

Tags: css

Could you please provide the best way of override and what is the advantages of this. For example.

**1. example :**

```
.ex1{
  font-size: 12px;
  color: green;
  text-align: left;
}

.custom .ex1{
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

**2. example**

```
.custom .ex1{
  font-size: 14px;
}
.ex1{
  font-size: 12px;
  color: green;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Which is one best way overriding, example 1 or example 2. if any advantages?

Comment: You might need to include some HTML that shows how these are used and what's overriding what. Is this special casing the `ex1` class inside of a `custom` class container?

Comment: In my understanding, example 2 is better. You should define all common styles first and then make them specific

Comment: both are output as same... but I need to know which is one best way to declare

Comment: There is no single correct answer to this question, it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: Since `.custom .ex1` has greater specificity, it will always be applied, so there's no difference, except in readability, which might suggest the first one is better.

Comment: It is based on practise and hence opinion based

Comment: @Rajesh But example 2 shows the specific one first, which is opposite to what you suggest.

Comment: @torazaburo `.custom .ex1` will have common property across classes. `.ex1{}` will have specific properties. Hence I gave an opinionated comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is really not much of a difference because compiling css is really easy for todays machines. But from what i know if you use it as example 1, it wouldnt look into .custom .ex1 because .ex1 has already been defined.

But as i said, it does not really matter. Its like going to police because someone took tiny dust of your sugar

Answer (score 0):

on css more you define an element more powerfull its css decleration for example in the exapmle you gave it is not the order gives override. It is `.custom` class, which defines `.ex1` more specifically since order does not change anything in this case you can do both. But personally I like starting from general classes and continue to specifics. I dont know but it feels more natural. therefore I would use following. However as I said there are no functional difference in this case.

```
.ex1{
  font-size: 12px;
  color: green;
  text-align: left;
}

.custom .ex1{
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have code like this -

```css
.main-class{
      font-size:24px;
      color:red;
  }
```

```html
<p class="main-class">Hi How are you?</p>
```

> Best way to override this CSS is to use a `sub class` which will override some properties of parent class like this -

```css
.main-class{
      font-size:24px;
      color:red;
  }
.sub-class{
    font-size:14px;
 }
```

```html
<p class="main-class sub-class">Hi How are you?</p>
```

Comment: The structure of op's post is different